# Hover will not work on my table when hovering between table divisions and table rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am attempting to make a table with multiple `tbody`s. And I would like the `background-color` of each `tbody` to change when a cursor is hovering over it. Currently the only issue is that the borders between the `td`s and `tr`s will not count it as hovering. The borders are still there even when `border = '0'`.

I made a jsFiddle showing the sort-of issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelMitchell/Pukqr/2/

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your fiddle doesn't have multiple tbodys and the borders do count as hovering as far as I'm concerned. Isn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s2m8W/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Nevermind, answered below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the gaps between cells are giving you this problem., add cellpadding=0 and cellspacing = 0 to your table,

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

Or CSS:

```
table { 
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

The green borders in your example appear as a result of the background of the table and the spaces between cells, if you want to see green borders add this code instead of the background to the table :

```
table td{
 border:1px solid green;   

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the `border-spacing` that was getting me.

Comment: I am glad it worked, I added more code in case you wanted to see the borders, accept the answer if it was what you were looking for, cheers.